# Error thrown when deserialising 2D Json Array using Jackson

Tags: java, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, jackson

I am trying to deserialize a two things from JSON. The format of the first one is as follows:

```
String json = "[{\"name\":\"Random\"," +
        "\"coordinates\":[[-3.1,55.4],[-3.1,55.9],[-3.7,55.3],[-3.8,55.7],[-3.0,55.8]]}]";
```

This is the second:

```
String json2 = "[{\"name\":\"Random\"," + "\"longitude\":-3.1, \"latitude\":55}]
```

My code is simple, and is as follows:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
var asArray = mapper.readValue(json, NoFlyZone[].class);
var asArray2 = mapper.readValue(json, LngLat.class);
```

The NoFlyZone class:

```
record NoFlyZone(LngLat[] coordinates) {

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("name")
    NoFlyZone (@JsonProperty("coordinates") double[][] coordinates) {
        this(doubleArrayToLngLatArray(coordinates));
    }
    private static LngLat[] doubleArrayToLngLatArray(double[][] coordinates) {
        var coordinateArray = new LngLat[coordinates.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
            coordinateArray[i] = new LngLat(coordinates[i][0], coordinates[i][1]);
        }
        System.out.println(coordinateArray);
        return coordinateArray;
    }

}
```

And finally, the LngLat class:

```
record LngLat(double lng, double lat) {

    LngLat (@JsonProperty("longitude") double lng,
            @JsonProperty("latitude") double lat) {
        this.lng = lng;
        this.lat = lat;
    }
}
```

I have tried deserialising them in the way shown above, but a MismatchedInputException is thrown when trying to deserialize the first string, with the error message "Cannot deserialize value of type `uk.ac.ed.inf.LngLat` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)...". I'm not sure why this is happening, so any help would be appreciated.

I have also tried adding the annotation

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
```

and fixing it as detailed in Alexander's answer, but then the second string throws an error when attempting to be deserialised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your record `LngLat` is represented as JSON-array (like `"[-3.1, 55.4]"`) you need to customize its deserialization.

And for that you can use [`@JsonFormat`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.9.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html) annotation providing the attribute `shape` with the value of [`JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.9.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.Shape.html). That would instruct Jackson to populate the record properties from the array in order of their declaration.

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
record LngLat(double lng, double lat) {}
```

And enclosing record `NoFlyZone` would be simplified to (*special method for parsing array of* `LngLat` *is redundant*):

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties("name")
record NoFlyZone(LngLat[] coordinates) {}
```

*Usage example:*

```
String json = "[{\"name\":\"Random\"," +
    "\"coordinates\":[[-3.1,55.4],[-3.1,55.9],[-3.7,55.3],[-3.8,55.7],[-3.0,55.8]]}]";
        
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<NoFlyZone>>() {}));
```

*Output:*
***note:** `toString()` method of the `NoFlyZone` has been overridden to display the array correctly*

```
[NoFlyZone{coordinates=[LngLat[lng=-3.1, lat=55.4], LngLat[lng=-3.1, lat=55.9], LngLat[lng=-3.7, lat=55.3], LngLat[lng=-3.8, lat=55.7], LngLat[lng=-3.0, lat=55.8]]}]
```

## Update

If you need to support the two **entirely different** structures of JSON, then you also need to customize deserialization on the `NoFlyZone` level (*because its JSON-shape differs*).

One of the ways to do that is to introduce the factory method annotated with [`@JsonCreator`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html). It would expect a single argument of type `Map<String, JsonNode>` in order to be able to funnel all the properties thought it.

We also need to set the attribute of `ignoreUnknown` of `@JsonIgnoreProperties` to `true`.

***Note:** the definition of `LngLat` remains the same (as shown above annotated with `@JsonFormat`).*

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public record NoFlyZone(LngLat[] coordinates) {
    
    @JsonCreator
    public static NoFlyZone getInstance(Map<String, JsonNode> fields) throws IOException {
        
        boolean isArray = fields.containsKey("coordinates");

        LngLat[] longLat;
        
        if (isArray) {
            ObjectReader reader = new ObjectMapper().readerFor(LngLat[].class);
            longLat = reader.readValue(fields.get("coordinates")); // parsing JsonNode which corresponds to "coordinates" property
        } else {
            longLat = new LngLat[] { // creating a single-element array
                new LngLat(
                    Double.parseDouble(fields.get("longitude").toString()),
                    Double.parseDouble(fields.get("latitude").toString())
                )
            };
        }
        return new NoFlyZone(longLat);
    }
    
    // toString()
}
```

*Usage example:*

```
String json1 = "[{\"name\":\"Random\"," +
    "\"coordinates\":[[-3.1,55.4],[-3.1,55.9],[-3.7,55.3],[-3.8,55.7],[-3.0,55.8]]}]";
    
String json2 = "[{\"name\":\"Random\"," + "\"longitude\":-3.1, \"latitude\":55}]";
        
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json1, new TypeReference<List<NoFlyZone>>() {}));
System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json2, new TypeReference<List<NoFlyZone>>() {}));
```

*Output:*

```
[NoFlyZone{coordinates=[LngLat[lng=-3.1, lat=55.4], LngLat[lng=-3.1, lat=55.9], LngLat[lng=-3.7, lat=55.3], LngLat[lng=-3.8, lat=55.7], LngLat[lng=-3.0, lat=55.8]]}]
[NoFlyZone{coordinates=[LngLat[lng=-3.1, lat=55.0]]}]
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but it causes another problem, which I should have mentioned before (apologies for taking up your time). I also have to deserialize the following from JSON: String json = "[{\"name\":\"Random\"," +
    "\"longitude\":-3.1, \"latitude\":55}] and build a LngLat object from that. Now I'm getting an error that says "Cannot deserialise a POJO(of type LngLat) from non-Array representation (token:START_OBJECT)." Thank you!

Comment: @BobMarley That's more tricky, but I think it's doable. And you really need to [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74600808/edit) the question and include these detail since it changes the problem.

Comment: @BobMarley So `"coordinates"` property might be completely absent, and instead there can be two properties "longitude" and "latitude" representing a single `LngLat` object, correct?

Comment: Yup, that is correct.

Comment: @BobMarley See the update. Is every thing fine now?